# XSL-FO: Forcing a page break between each <xi:include>

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, docbook

I'm trying to generate a mod spec with pdf generation.  The way I have it be generated is using a contents.xml file which looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook http://schema.5d.ca/docbook/docbook.xsd
                    http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude http://schema.5d.ca/docbook/XInclude.xsd">

<title>Mod Spec</title>
<?dbfo-need height="8in" space-before="3em" ?>
<xi:include href="first.xml"/>    
<section>
    <title>View Stuff</title>
    <xi:include href="./stuff/panel.xml"/>
</section>
<section>
    <title>Nav things</title>
    <xi:include href="./things/about.xml"/>        
    <xi:include href="./things/control.xml"/>
    <xi:include href="./things/launch.xml"/>        
</section>
...(more sections with includes)
</article>
```

Now I also have a stylesheet that sets header, footer, and table style stuff before the above xml is sent off for XSL-FO, and this stylesheet will need to add the page breaks.

So my question is:  How do do I add a page break between all my sperate modspecs in contents.xml?

**EDIT**
http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PageBreaking.html States I should add this to my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('hard-pagebreak')">
   <fo:block break-after='page'/>
</xsl:template>
```

So that it picks up `<?hard-pagebreak?>` in the .xml files.  I would like to keep the solution as compact as possible, so how do I edit my stylesheet so that a first pass will add the `<?hard-pagebreak?>` after each `<xi:include>` followed by the template given my sagehill?

Comment: @Ace: If by "page break" you mean an XSL-FO page break, this is not about XSLT itself.

Comment: @Alejandro: Perhaps this is naiave of me, but is there a 'new page' or 'page break' character, that would have the effect?

Comment: @Ace: That would be a fair DocBook question...

Comment: @Alejandro:Yes, but the stylesheet will be the only way I could implement this change, whether its fixing contents.xml or all the other .xml files

Comment: @Ace: Maybe, but first you need to know wich specific XML vocabulary's element to use.

Comment: @Alejandro: Accroding to: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PageBreaking.html I can add in hard breaks, using `<?hard-pagebreak?>`, how do I insert that between my `<xi:include>`?

Comment: @Ace: Good catch! But I think you need to read the documentation careful: it's telling you to use `<fo:block break-after='page'/>`. Now you can rephrase your question with this information for an XSLT solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force page breaks in the output, the idea is that you should add `<?hard-pagebreak?>` processing instructions directly, by hand, to the XML source document (the same way you have already added `<?dbfo-need height="8in" space-before="3em"?>`), and put

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('hard-pagebreak')">
  <fo:block break-after='page'/>  
</xsl:template>
```

in the stylesheet customization layer. If you want, you could use @Alejandro's suggestion which adds the PIs using an extra transformation step, but you don't really need that (IMHO).

Comment: Unfortunatly adding the `<?hard-pagebreak?>` is unrealistic given the number of files I'd need to do it to, and it'd also reduce the readability of the contents.xml file (which is also used for html generation.

Comment: Ideally this solution is mixed with Alejandro's, so his first, then this one.

Answer (score 3):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="xi:include">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="hard-pagebreak"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<article xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook http://schema.5d.ca/docbook/docbook.xsd
           http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude http://schema.5d.ca/docbook/XInclude.xsd"
         xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <title>Mod Spec</title>
    <?dbfo-need height="8in" space-before="3em" ?>
    <xi:include href="first.xml"></xi:include>
    <?hard-pagebreak?>
    <section>
        <title>View Stuff</title>
        <xi:include href="./stuff/panel.xml"></xi:include>
        <?hard-pagebreak?>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>Nav things</title>
        <xi:include href="./things/about.xml"></xi:include>
        <?hard-pagebreak?>
        <xi:include href="./things/control.xml"></xi:include>
        <?hard-pagebreak?>
        <xi:include href="./things/launch.xml"></xi:include>
        <?hard-pagebreak?>
    </section> ...(more sections with includes) 
</article>
```

So, then you can add that template matching ***fictitious*** `hard-pagebreak` processing instruction **into the DocBook to FOP stylesheet**

Comment: @Alejandro, this is close.  Ideally I want to add this solution in with my existing stylesheet, i.e. first pass it adds in the `<?hard-pagebreak?>` second pass it processes it.

Comment: @Ace: You should add that second step in the DocBook stylesheet as explaned in your linked document.

Comment: @Alejandro: I wish to have them in the same stylesheet.  The stylesheet I have is run just before xsl-fo is done and only applies to the pdf that is generated.  I don't want it to effect any other type of doc that is generated.

Comment: @Alejandro, why do you say that the PI is "fictitious"? I would say that it is a very "real" PI.

Comment: @mzjn: Because it's fictitious for the DocBook processing (as it won't be matched by any template in the DocBook stylesheet, except built-in of course...). So, @Ace needs to add a template matching this PI for converting to an XSL-FO element (this `<fo:block break-after='page'/>`). Why in the DocBook stylesheet and not before? Because we don't know what DocBook stylesheet is going to do when finding this XSL-FO element. Most probably, it's going to ignore it and then it won't reach the FOP processing.

Comment: @Alejandro, I know how the PI works. The standard DocBook FO stylesheet won't do anything with it; you need an extra template in a customization layer (as it says at http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PageBreaking.html#HardPageBreaks). Calling the PI "fictitious" is not very helpful.

Comment: @Alejandro: IS it possible to have pass1, pass2?  I'm thinking having one template after the other simply won't work.

Comment: @Ace: The only solution for a one step transformation is importing the DocBook stylesheet in my stylesheet match `xsi:include` adding the XSL-FO element and then `xsl:apply-import`

Comment: @Alejandro:I tried using that technique and just got errors like: `WARNING: Unknown formatting object http://docbook.org/ns/docbook^para` and fatal error at the end saying `fo:root is missing child elements.`

Comment: @Alejandro: I tried your stylesheet by itself on content.xml and the only thing that happened was the it was flattened (all the `xincludes` were replaced with the actual xml they represent).  There was no `<?hard-pagebreak?>` added :(

Comment: @Ace: You run something else besides my stylesheet for `xi:include` elements replacement...

Comment: @Alejandro: Nope, although I think I see a problem with this whole thing.  anytime you run any stylesheet on contents.xml it immeadiatly get flattens and all the `xi:includes` are resolved before any script is run.

Comment: @Ace: if your XML parser does XInclude processing, then Alejandro's stylesheet won't work, since all the `<xi:include>` elements will have been replaced by the referenced content by the time the XSLT processor sees the source document.

Comment: @Ace: I'm sure that you can pass a parameter to the XSLT processor to so the parser doesn't use the XInclude processor.

Comment: @Alejandro: Well, I'd want it not to parse when the `<?hard-pagebreak?>` stylesheet is ran, but then to parse as normal when the bigger one with `<fo:block break-after='page'/>` is ran

Comment: I found this, but this looks like code and not xml http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xinclude.html